# Como agir perante resposta num idioma que não o português?

Tags: debate, respostas, idioma

Na fila de *"Publicações de baixa qualidade"* deparei-me com uma resposta dada em inglês.
A minha reação imediata foi recomendar a exclusão, no entanto, quando chegou a altura de justificar, não havia nenhuma opção que se aplicasse.

Deverá ser incluída essa opção ou não devemos excluir essas respostas?

<sub>Entretanto a [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/68801/2541) já foi traduzida</sub>

Comment: A resposta deve ser excluída se não for traduzida (pelo autor ou por outra pessoa). Mas deve-se esperar um tempo antes de votar para excluir. A versão em inglês nem consta do histórico de edição da resposta, sinal de que a tradução ocorreu nos primeiros 5 minutos após a publicação. Extremamente cedo. Quanto a votar contra, fica a seu critério, se vir algum problema na qualidade do conteúdo. Um problema de tradução (ou ortografia, ou sintaxe) não justifica o voto contra, já que pode ser facilmente sanado por uma edição de *qualquer* usuário.

Comment: @bfavaretto na verdade o autor não editou a resposta, ele traduziu e publicou uma nova, apagando a [versão em Inglês](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/68785/3117). Para ser mais preciso, a versão em Inglês ficou no ar por 30 minutos.

Comment: Ops, deixei passar isso. Mas 30 minutos pra mim ainda está dentro do razoável para esperar (precisa também checar o último acesso do usuário antes de apagar).

Comment: @bfavaretto e se toda a gente que estiver a ver a resposta não perceber inglês? Flag para o moderador?

Comment: @Math - Desculpe estar a voltar ao assunto mas, após ponderar, julgo que devo considerar legitima qualquer edição feita para corrigir palavras que não estejam segundo o acordo ortográfico. Assim, continuarei a escrever na forma antiga, sem protestar qualquer edição feita.

Comment: Possivelmente esta [resposta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2177/como-proceder-quando-a-resposta-aceite-n%C3%A3o-esta-em-portugu%C3%AAs) e relevante para o assunto.

Comment: Parece-me então, considerando o comentário do @bfavaretto e a [resposta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/2178/2541) que o **omni** refere, que as respostas devem ser tratados da mesma forma que as perguntas. Fica apenas a questão de não haver nenhuma opção justificativa, que se aplique, no quadro da fila de análise.

Comment: @ramaral eu costumo fazer esse tipo de mudanças pq aqui no Brasil o novo acordo não gerou discussões, todo mundo aceitou e pronto :) Entretanto eu não sei como foi a reação dos portugueses com relação a isso, talvez tenha gerado algum mal estar entre a população, nunca tinha parado pra pensar nisso antes, então eu simplesmente não sei. Caso em Portugal ainda seja comum o uso do "c" mudo não sou eu que vou forçar o jeito brasileiro de escrever, mas se retirá-lo não lhe incomoda, pode deixar retirado :)